# After checking if a record exist, and it doesn't, SaveChanges gives an DbUpdateException

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have a table that has a unique index on two columns, *F1* and *Kant*[1]. There is no Foreign Keys just Primary Key (which is an integer Id) and this index.

Before I add a new record I do a check if a record with this index exists in the database.[2]
I get that it doesn't! *ExistsLaserData* returns false.

I then add the record to the *DbSet* and execute *SaveChanges* but now I get an exception

> DbUpdateException:  SqlException: Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint
>   'IX_laserdata_F1_Kant'.  Cannot insert duplicate key in object
>   'dbo.LaserData'.  The duplicate key value is (123456, NULL).

This is the record I have added!

The context is initialized with

```
LaserDataContext context = new LaserDataContext();
OrderBy(x => x.F1).ThenBy(x => x.Kant).ToList();
```

The two methods that I'm using

```
public bool ExistsLaserData(string article, string kant)
{
    bool result = false;
    var found = _context.LaserData.Where(x => x.F1 == article && x.Kant == kant).FirstOrDefault();
    if (found != null)
    {
        result = true;
    }

    return result;
}

public void AddLaserData(ref LaserData d)
{
    try
    {
        _context.LaserData.Add(d);
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
```

}

**Why does the record not exist when I check for it or why does it exist when I do SaveChanges?**

[1] The beginning of this database was an Excel document, thus the strange names...

[2] I don't want to skip the ExistLaserData check, so please don't suggest that I should just use the exception.

Comment: I usually try add which returns number of rows entered.  If I get zero then use update to change value.  When you have a primary key only one row is allowed in datatable for each unique id.

Comment: If there's any possibility that this system is used by multiple users and that these key values are user supplied, then *no* amount of "pre-checking" can save you from a race and so you *will* have to handle the exception *anyway*.

Comment: Yes, but then I can handle it like an exception, which I do. But this is in a dialog for adding a new record and I would like to give the user a 'hint' that he is trying to add a record that already exists...

Answer (score 0):

I think you should cast the article to integer then check if that exists or not.

As you said F1 is int and article is string so you can not compare them.

Then you can use this for add or update :

```
LaserData found = _context.LaserData.FirstOrDefault( p => p.F1==(int) article);
if(found == null)
{
    _context.LaserData.Add(d);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}
```

I hope this helps you. maybe you need to explain more if this is not you want.

if the article type is like F1 so u can write without cast to int :

```
LaserData found = _context.LaserData.FirstOrDefault( p => p.F1== article);
```

You do not have to check kant if it is not unique. But you can check if u like.

Edit :
just use this :

```
public bool ExistsLaserData(string article, string kant)
{
bool result = false;
LaserData found = _context.LaserData.FirstOrDefault(x => x.F1 == article && x.Kant == kant);
if (found != null)
{
    result = true;
}

return result;
```

}

Comment: No F1 is a NVARCHAR(50)  and Kant is CHAR(1). There is also an Id which is an IDENTITY INT which is the primary key. I have an index on the two columns F1 and Kant which is UNIQUE.

Comment: Tried it and I get the same exception.

Comment: I think this is best way for u : LaserData found = _context.LaserData.FirstOrDefault( p => p.F1== article && p.kant==kant);
if(found == null)
{
    _context.LaserData.Add(d);
    _context.SaveChanges();
}

Answer (score 0):

Here you are checking for both the values in the same row and it returns a row only if both the keys are the same for a single row.

Can you try this? Instead of && , use ||

```
public bool ExistsLaserData(string article, string kant)
{
    bool result = false;
    var found = _context.LaserData.Where(x => x.F1 == article || x.Kant == kant).FirstOrDefault();
    if (found != null)
    {
        result = true;
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: I think I expressed myself a bit clumsy. It's one index that contains both F1 and Kant. The combination of these two columns must be unique, but there may be many values for F1 that are the same (with different values for Kant) and also many values for Kant that are the save (with different values for F1). So wouldn't that make me have to use && ?

Comment: Yes you should use && in this way you say. I think if you use LaserData for found it's better and maybe that's why It returns false.

Comment: Ok.. Yes, you are right. You should use '&&' in that case. 
Can you please add the calling methods too?
And also you could use the Any instead of Where.

bool found = _context.LaserData.Any(x => x.F1 == article && x.Kant == kant);

Comment: True he can use this too : return _context.LaserData.Any(x => x.F1 == article && x.Kant == kant); for a shorter code <3

Answer (score 0):

More likely than not your `kant` property is not properly mapped. This would explain both the Exception and the behavior of the code.

- The Exception states you tried to insert a `null` value for `kant` which would make sense because EF never sent over a value due to the incorrect mapping.
- `ExistsLaserData` always returns `false` as long as you do not pass `null` into the method for the `kant` parameter. This would lead your code to always try the `AddLaserData` method.

So the fix is to ensure that this property is properly mapped and to correct column.

---

If that is not it then you are trying to insert multiple records with the same `F1` value but with a `null` `kant` value which would break the unique index. The only way around that is to alter the index with a `where` filter so that it only checks when the `kant` has a value.

```
CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_laserdata_F1_Kant] ON dbo.LaserData (F1 ASC, Kant ASC) WHERE (Kant IS NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have found where the error occurs and it has nothing to do with the ExistsLaserData to do. ExistsLaserData works perfectly!

since this is a whole new problem I will make a new question

Thanks for all of your suggestions, I will use some of them!

PS! As a teaser. In the override of SaveChanges event I Trim() all fields that are strings. This does something that make the base.SaveChanges throw an exception...